# pg gem: 'Warning: no type cast defined for type "numeric" '

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I'm having trouble getting typed results out of the pg gem.

```
require 'pg'                                                            
require_relative 'spec/fixtures/database'                               

client = PG.connect( DB[:pg] )                                            
client.type_map_for_queries = PG::BasicTypeMapForQueries.new(client)    
client.type_map_for_results = PG::BasicTypeMapForResults.new(client)    

client.exec( %|select * from testme;| ) do |query|                        
  query.each {|r| puts r.inspect }                                      
end
```

This program gives the output:

```
Warning: no type cast defined for type "money" with oid 790. Please cast this type explicitly to TEXT to be safe for future changes.
Warning: no type cast defined for type "numeric" with oid 1700. Please cast this type explicitly to TEXT to be safe for future changes.
{"string"=>"thing", "logical"=>true, "cash"=>"£1.23", "reel"=>"2.34", "day"=>#<Date: 2015-12-31 ((2457388j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, "float"=>3.45}
```

So: booleans and floats and dates (and integers) get converted, but not numerics or the money type.

Can anyone tell me how to "cast the type explicitly", assuming that I don't want to hard-code a solution for each table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the same problem with a text-ish field. Solved by duplicating a coder and editing its OID.

```
text_coder = client.type_map_for_results.coders.find { |c| c.name == 'text' }
new_coder = text_coder.dup.tap { |c| c.oid = 19 } # oid from the warning
conn.type_map_for_results.add_coder(new_coder)
```

---

---

---

**How I got there:** it might interest the next guy, if the problem is similar but not identical.

I read other people online talking about `type_map_for_results`, but how they didn't know how to define a coder. Since it was a text field in my case, I decided to try cloning an existing one. I knew I could find a textual pre-set in a Rails app, so I opened a `rails console` and searched:

```
adapter = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
connection = adapter.instance_variable_get("@connection")
mapping = connection.type_map_for_results
cd mapping  # my console of choice is `pry`
ls          # spotted a likely getter named `coders`
cd coders   # again
ls          # spotted getter `name` and setter `oid=`
```

So I put together the code in the solution. Gave it a try, and it worked.

It had not been straightforward to find, so I decided to exit lurker mode and share it on SO. Thereby: thanks [@Andreyy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/567938/andreyy) for bringing me in :)

[[pry `cd` and `ls`](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/State-navigation)]

Comment: PS after so many years of lurking, I just joined SO and this is my first contribution. Guidance appreciated ;)

Comment: There's a typo in your code (`new_coder` -> `name_coder`) and it would have taken me two minutes instead of five to check your answer had you shown the error message. But none of that matters. You have solved what no-one else could, even when I offered a bounty.  Tick, tick, tick. Many thanks!

Comment: I got no error to show, since I use `name_coder` in my implementation. My field is actually aptly named `name`, hence my choice of `name_coder`, which unfortunately echos `c.name` in the code... confused yet? That's why I (tried to) change the name :P Thanks for spotting the last one of them, I was pretty much burned out for the day when I wrote this answer. Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 5):

Hijacking this thread, as after some digging I finally found a way to add a custom decoder/encoder, so posting an example below:

```
require 'ipaddr'
require 'pg'

class InetDecoder < PG::SimpleDecoder
  def decode(string, tuple=nil, field=nil)
    IPAddr.new(string)
  end
end
class InetEncoder < PG::SimpleEncoder
  def encode(ip_addr)
    ip_addr.to_s
  end
end

# 0 if for text format, can also be 1 for binary
PG::BasicTypeRegistry.register_type(0, 'inet', InetEncoder, InetDecoder)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a catch all for those seeking to cast strings by default:

```
client = PG.connect( DB[:pg] )           

map = PG::BasicTypeMapForResults.new(conn)
map.default_type_map = PG::TypeMapAllStrings.new

client.type_map_for_results = map
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Google the error message: "Warning: no type cast defined for type"
2. You can find it's source [github](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/blob/master/lib/pg/basic_type_mapping.rb#L274).
3. Reding the class, I would guess lines from 150 to 214 could be consiredered 
   examples:

   - `register_type 0, 'text', PG::TextEncoder::String`
   - `alias_type 0, 'varchar', 'text'`
4. Since register_type and alias_type are class methods of `PG::BasicTypeRegistry::CoderMap` I would play with them just and see if anything changes:

   - `PG::BasicTypeRegistry::CoderMap.alias_type 0, 'money', 'text'`
   - `PG::BasicTypeRegistry::CoderMap.alias_type 0, 'numeric', 'text'`

Reading the comments in the class it seems that the coding/decoding of those and some other fields is not implemented.

You might consider using a higher level ORM library like AvtiveRecord which implements more types ([money](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/oid/money.rb)).

Comment: Of course, I have already done these things. I think perhaps that if Pg was able to support Money just by passing 'money' as a string to Codermap, it would already do so?  I'm pretty certain I need to create a new Coder object that translates numeric and money types to a BigDecimal. But nothing in the source I've seen so far tells me how to configure a new Coder object, or where to plug it in...

Comment: What about taking one of the difined coder/decoder pirs as example?
https://goo.gl/3Dhe5c

Comment: "Nothing in the source I've seen so far tells me how to configure a new Coder object"